# Table-caption rotated wrongly

Tags: tables, r, tufte

How can the table-description in `tufte-handouts` be placed correctly with `sideways`-tables and `xtable`? See following minimal reproducible example where the figure-description is corrrect (stolen from tikzDevice-manual), but the table-description is not. I have been struggling with finding a solution, but without success. I need the table- and figure-descriptions to be placed consistently.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
<<plotchunk, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE>>=
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("tikz-example.tex",
width = 3.25, height = 3.25)
plot(1, 1, main = "Hello \\TeX !")
@
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{tikz-example.tex}
\caption{This figure-description is where it should be, and with the correct direction}
\end{figure}
<<tablechunk, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
example.df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=20))
x.small <- xtable(example.df, label=NULL, caption="This is the table description that should not be sideways, but placed similarly as the figure-description")
digits(x.small) <- 0
print(x.small,include.rownames=FALSE,floating.environment="sidewaystable")
@
\end{document}
```

If the sideways-table can be rotated 180 degrees, that would be great too, but not necessary.

Comment: Is the R code really necessary for the example? Much simpler for us who know nothing of R/knitr/sweave if you add some `sidewaystable`s directly. If you do need it, can you explain how to run the example? Have you experimented with the `clockwise`/`counterclockwise` or `figuresleft`/`figuresright` class option (see the manual, section 2.1).